# Wireless Comms in Medieval battles

Tags: internal-consistency

What effect would wireless comms have in a medieval battles of only one army had them?

For example modern police radios.

Comment: If you're going to downvote this, at least tell the OP why. This isn't very long and doesn't seem to be a considered question, but I upvoted it because you can't fix what's wrong if no one says. OP should likely should beef up this question a bit. And, it doesn't have to be radios, it can be any device/magic that has the same effect.

Comment: @ErinThursby You can use your upvotes for what you wish, but the generally accepted use of upvotes is to push **good questions** to the top, not correct downvotes that you deem unworthy. That being said, this question is too broad.

Comment: What would I need to add to become less broad?

Comment: @Aify I know. I think it's a neat question, just short.

Comment: For it to be less broad, ask how it would affect the outcome of a particular type of battle, given certain ground, and the range of the signal. Basically, get specific. Questions need to be well researched and structured themselves. Also, how many of these devices? Who has them? These are all factors that must be defined before we can answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Great** (given long range) for spies. If you know where your opponent is (and is going) and what he's got ahead of time, that's got to help a lot in your planning.

**Good** for scouts. They can report back instantly, instead of having to ride back with a report - so that gives you a faster response time.

**Probably not too much impact** for control in a normal battle; armies have ways of passing commands already. Radio makes that a bit faster, but not hugely - though there may be times where saving a few minutes could make all the difference.

**Maybe** handy for kicking off surprise attacks from a hidden force - but if you can hide your force, then it's probably not too hard to hide an observer watching for a signal.

I suspect the spying/scouting advantage would be the big thing. If you can attack the enemy's resources when he's not there to defend them, yet still know when he's coming after you, that has to be a big, big, advantage.

Comment: I believe you underestimate the effect in a battle. As an example, the Charge of the Light Brigade was carried out as the result of an unclear order, that the brigade leader did not have time to confirm. A radio would have prevented that particular catastrophe.

Comment: Interesting point - but it's doubtful if it would have helped the Light brigade:

Comment: From Wikipedia: "The order was drafted by Brigadier Richard Airey and carried by Captain Louis Edward Nolan. Nolan carried the further oral instruction that the cavalry was to attack immediately. When Lucan asked what guns were referred to, Nolan is said to have indicated with a wide sweep of his arm—not the causeway redoubts—but the mass of Russian guns in a redoubt at the end of the valley, around a mile away. His reasons for the misdirection are unknown because he was killed in the ensuing battle." So it was queried, and Nolan got it wrong.

Comment: I think my point is that with radio Airey could have been asked directly which guns he meant.

Comment: Which is why it's a good point - being able to ask for clarification quickly would certainly be handy. On the other hand, Lucan did ask - and got the wrong answer. If Nolan wasn't certain - or Lucan thought he wasn't certain - then a radio would have helped - but given the assumption that the messenger who'd talked to the person issuing the order knew what he meant, and that the order needed immediate action, would Lucan have queried it again when delay might be fatal?  radio could have prevented it - I'm just doubtful whether it would have.